# nominal to bi-nominal in python

Tags: python, numpy

To convert any field to binomial, we need to add a number of components to your feature vector (header) equal to the number of possible values in that field. Then, if a data point has the ith value, you set the ith one of those components to 1, and the rest for that attribute to 0

e.g. consider following dataset

```
array = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat'])
```

result i am expecting is `result = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed answer is fine but you may also consider using pandas for this:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: can we have reverse of this ? which will give me 1-D array of binominal form array?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge. If you're sure to have proper dummies, based on your exemple: `df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]), columns = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'])`, you can do somehing like this `ar_back = [row[row == 1].index[0] for row_i, row in df_test.iterrows()]`

Answer (score 1):

A three-liner. First create a list which maps `cat`, `dog` and `mouse` to a number, which is their position in the list, then create an array to manipulate. Finally use a list comprehension to do the mapping.

```
m = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
x = np.array([1, 0, 0])
result = np.array([np.roll(x, m.index(value)) for value in array])
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

If you want to handle values which are not in `m`, then the list comprehension can be modified as follows:

```
arr = np.array(['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'cat', None, 'dog']) # Example array
result = np.array([np.roll(x, m.index(value)) if  value in m else np.zeros(len(m)) for value in arr])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: what if i am having None or np.nan values in array, the output for None should be all zero's i.e. [0, 0, 0]

Comment: See my edit to the original answer - I've modified the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

In common python

```py
def binom(arr):
    seen = set()
    values = []
    for item in arr:
        if item in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(item)
        values.append(item)

    result = []
    for item in arr:
        r = [0] * len(values)
        r[values.index(item)] = 1
        result.append(r)
    return result
```

Comment: this script not giving me exact result. it gives `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]` the position of 'cat' and 'mouse' changed

Comment: @rohan_tare i updated solution with preserving ordering when creating values. My mistake.